# Validation failed error in Rails application and Cucumber with Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cucumber, factory-bot

I have the following error: "Validation failed: Email address is already used" while trying to run feature for Devise user signing in.

I suspect the problem is in Factory generated user, which somehow being created twice with the same email address. I tried to run rake db:test:prepare in order to reset test database, unfortunately, with no results.

my **user_factory.rb**

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.email "user_#{rand(1000).to_s}@example.com"
  user.password "password"
  user.confirmed_at nil
end
```

Steps, which are failing with validation error are **"Then I should be registered and signed in"** and **"And user signs in"**. my **signing_in.feature**

```
Feature: Signing in
  In order to use the site
  As a user
  I want to be able to sign in

  Scenario: Signing in via confirmation
    Given there is an unconfirmed user
    And I open the email with subject "Confirmation instructions"
    And they click the first link in the email
    Then I should be registered and signed in

  Scenario: Signing in via form
    Given there is a confirmed user
    And I am on the homepage
    And user signs in
    Then I should see "Signed in successfully"
```

my **user_steps.rb**

```
def unconfirmed_user
  @unconfirmed_user = Factory(:user)
end


def sign_up user
  visit '/users/sign_up'
  fill_in('Email', :with => "unique@unique.com")
  fill_in('Password', :with => user.password)
  fill_in('Password confirmation', :with => user.password)
  click_button('Sign up')
end

def sign_in user
  visit 'users/sign_in'
  fill_in('Email', :with => user.email)
  fill_in('Password', :with => user.password)
  click_button('Sign in')
end

When /^I'm signing up$/ do
  sign_up unconfirmed_user
end

Given /^there is an unconfirmed user$/ do
  unconfirmed_user
end

Given /^there is a confirmed user$/ do
  unconfirmed_user.confirm!
end

Then /^I should be registered and signed in$/ do
  page.should have_content("Signed in as #{unconfirmed_user.email}")
end

Given /^user signs in$/ do
  sign_in unconfirmed_user.confirm!
end

When /^I open the email with subject "([^"]*?)"$/ do |subject|
  open_email(@unconfirmed_user.email, :with_subject => subject)
end
```

What it can be?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be clearing the database between tests, mostly using [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner). Check the manual because configuration varies between setups. We are using this one (in `env.rb`):

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
Before do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

Also, you should remove the `rand` directive in the factories file and use the goodies FactoryGirl provides:

```
 u.sequence(:email){|n| "user_#{n}@example.com" }
```

Comment: Also, shouldn't you be filling in the email field with user.email in the signup method too?